# algorithm2e options algonl and boxed seem to clash

Tags: numbering, algorithm2e, overflow

I'm using a solution suggested by [C. Fiorio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89629/c-fiorio) in [Want Knuth style line numbering in algorithm2e algorithms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373352/want-knuth-style-line-numbering-in-algorithm2e-algorithms).  The suggestion was to use the **algonl** option for algorithm2e to achieve Knuth style algorithm line numbering; i.e. Algorithm #3 should have lines numbered 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, etc.    However it seems the line number overflow the bounding box if I use the **boxed** option.

Can someone suggest a good way to fix this so that the algorithm box does not clash with the line numbering?

Here is what I see rendered.
[image]

Here is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noend,boxed,linesnumbered,algonl]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{}{end}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]\label{algo.find.augmenting.path}
  \caption{Implementation of function to find an augmenting path if one exists.}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \Fn{find-augmenting-path-or-none$(adj,E,M)$}{
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    \Input{$adj$ adjacency list of simple graph}
    \Input{$E$ set of edges}
    \Input{$M$ a matching}
    \BlankLine
    $free \gets $ generate-free-vertices() \;
    \If{$|free| < 2$}{
      \Return None \;
    }
    \tcp*[l]{Find set of length=2 paths starting at a free vertex}
    $paths \gets \{[u,v] \mid u\in free, \{u,v\} \in E  \}$\label{algo.line.paths.1b}\;
    $k \gets 1$  \tcp*{index of 2nd element of 0-index-based array}
    \While{$paths \neq \emptyset$}{
      \If{odd$(k)$}{
        \For{$p \in paths$}{
          \If{ $p_k \in free$ }{
            \Return p\;
          }
        }
      }
      $paths \gets$ extend-alternating-path$(adj,M,k,free,paths)$ \;
      $k \gets k+1$ \;
    }
    \Return None
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a larger `\algomargin` solves the problem. You can

- directly set `\setlength\algomargin{3em}` or
- use `\IncMargin{<length>}` to add `<length>` to `\algomargin`.

See the [documentation of `algorithm2e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf), sec. 9.6.

Alternatively, you can

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noend,boxed,linesnumbered,algonl]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{}{end}

\setlength\algomargin{3em}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]\label{algo.find.augmenting.path}
  \caption{Implementation of function to find an augmenting path if one exists.}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \Fn{find-augmenting-path-or-none$(adj,E,M)$}{
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    \Input{$adj$ adjacency list of simple graph}
    \Input{$E$ set of edges}
    \Input{$M$ a matching}
    \BlankLine
    $free \gets $ generate-free-vertices() \;
    \If{$|free| < 2$}{
      \Return None \;
    }
    \tcp*[l]{Find set of length=2 paths starting at a free vertex}
    $paths \gets \{[u,v] \mid u\in free, \{u,v\} \in E  \}$\label{algo.line.paths.1b}\;
    $k \gets 1$  \tcp*{index of 2nd element of 0-index-based array}
    \While{$paths \neq \emptyset$}{
      \If{odd$(k)$}{
        \For{$p \in paths$}{
          \If{ $p_k \in free$ }{
            \Return p\;
          }
        }
      }
      $paths \gets$ extend-alternating-path$(adj,M,k,free,paths)$ \;
      $k \gets k+1$ \;
    }
    \Return None
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: output showing larger \algomargin]

Comment: Thanks muzimuzhi Z, that works well.

Comment: @JimNewton If you like the proposed answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: @BambOo, thanks for the suggestion.  I had upvoted it, but forgot to click the checkmark.  Thanks for the kind reminder.